# PHP regex split on @.*?>

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I created a simple templating/content parser where you can specify where blocks of text should be placed in the final output page. The "markup" I settled on is something like @blockname> on it's own line. So to put a block of text in the body, you would start the text with @body>. The blockname can be anything you want to use, but it can't contain spaces or line breaks.

Everything works fine, except if there is a text string like @body> embedded in the text. It splits on the embedded text too. This seems really simple, I just want to match a line that starts with @ followed by any non-white space characters and ending with > at the end of the line. The command I have right now that almost works is:

```
preg_split('/@([^\s].*?[^>])>/', $tpl, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

It seems I should just be able to use ^@([^\s].*?[^>])>$, but that doesn't work at all. I feel I'm missing something simple. I've tried a bunch of modifiers at the end to no avail.

Example text to parse:

```
@css>
.example {font-weight:bold;}

@js>
function example() {
    alert('example');
}

@body>
This is some sample @body> text to show
```

That ideally the regex split would come back with:

```
Array
(
[0] => css
[1] => 
.example {font-weight:bold;}
[2] => js
[3] => 
function example() {
alert('example');
}
[4] => body
[5] => 
This is some sample @body> text to show
```

Comment: `^` only matches the start of the string, not the start of each line. Either use modifiers to match at each line or split your string beforehand.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to define an escape sequence? Just tell users that if they want something that looks like a markup tag in the body of the content, it must be escaped? That is, after all, the purpose of things like `&lt;`, `&gt;` etc in HTML - to overcome the exact problem that you have...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just want to match a line that starts with @ followed by any
>   non-white space characters and ending with > at the end of the line.

You can do that with:

```
"/^@(\\S+)>$/m"
```

With PHP quoting. You were probably missing the `/m` switch which makes `^`/`$` match beginning/end of lines, and not only strings.

Comment: That seems to be only parsing on the first instance it encounters. Why the double \\ in front of the S?

Comment: Because `\ ` needs to be escaped in double quoted strings. And it works just fine, eg http://ideone.com/6DOtg , altho I'd use `preg_replace`/`preg_replace_callback` for this.

Comment: Finally discovered that preg_split is working different on different systems. On my OSX 10.8/PHP 5.3.6 system your suggestion works fine. On my Debian Squeeze/PHP 5.3.3 setup it fails completely, no parsing.